# Why Node created by Document.adoptNode(node) does not contain values for attributes?

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have an  xml XML1  like

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c></c>
    <c someAttrib="hi"></c>
  <b>
<a>
```

and an another XML 2 like

```
  <b>
    <c someAttrib="hello"></c>
  <b>
```

If i do

```
 DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  
    InputStream a=new ByteArrayInputStream(XML1.getBytes());
        InputStream b=new ByteArrayInputStream(XML2.getBytes());
        Document doc1 = builder.parse(a);
        doc1.getDocumentElement().normalize ();
        Document doc2 = builder.parse(b);
        doc2.getDocumentElement().normalize ();

        XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();

        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("a/b");

        NodeList qa=(NodeList)expr.evaluate(doc1,XPathConstants.NODESET);
        Node oldConfigurationNode=qa.item(0);

         doc1.createAttribute("operation");
         doc2.getFirstChild().getAttributes().item(0);
         Node newConfigurationNode=doc1.adoptNode(doc2.getFirstChild());

         oldConfigurationNode.getParentNode().replaceChild(newConfigurationNode, ConfigurationNode);

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); 
            Transformer serializer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(); 
            serializer.transform(new DOMSource(doc1.getFirstChild()), new StreamResult(sw));
           System.out.println(sw.toString());
```

The output that i get is

```
 <a>
   <b>
     <c att=""/>
   </b>
 </a>
```

What does adopt node method actually does ,i am getting different results on different scenario.

Why is this behaviour? Please explain this.. Thank u

Answer (score 3):

In the [documentation of adoptNode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#adoptNode(org.w3c.dom.Node)) you can see:

> ELEMENT_NODE
>   Specified attribute nodes of the source element are adopted. **Default attributes are discarded**, though if the document being adopted into defines default attributes for this element name, those are assigned.

If you want to keep original values you can use [importNode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#importNode(org.w3c.dom.Node,%20boolean)) method with the paramter *deep* set to true.